# java array to print square box of asterisk

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write a square shape of asterisk around border using the https://stackoverflow.com/a/34209565  answer.

But I cannot get it working at all.

Here is the code I'm trying.

```
    int _i = 10;
    int _j = 10;
    String[][] array = new String[_i][_j];
    for (int i = 0; i < _i; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int j = 0; j < _j; j++) {
            if(i==0 || j == 0 || i == _i - 1|| j == _j - 1){
                array[i][j] = "*";
                System.out.print(array[i][j]);

            }
        }
    }
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
**********
**
**
**
**
**
**
**
**
**********
```

I tried running tthe code from the answer but it produces a  one line of asterisk. Something from the code in the answer has been omitted.

The code provdied in the answer is:

```
int _i = 10;
int _j = 10;
String[][] array = new String[_i][_j];
for (int i = 0; i < _i; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < _j; j++) {
        if(i==0 || j == 0 || i == _i-1|| j == _j-1){
            array[i][j] = "*";
        }
    }
}
```

And the output in the answer is:

```
**********
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
**********
```

Comment: It seems that you already have a sample of code that produces the correct result, so what is your question?

Comment: I tried running that but it produces a  one line of asterisk. You should try the code, it is no useful at all. Something from the code in the answer has been omitted.

Comment: The provided code produces a 2-dimension array that is filled out with asterisks around the borders and nulls everywhere else.  If you print out `array`, it will produce the required box.  There's some nuance to printing out the array, but it's not too terribly tricky.

Comment: it was missing a else statement that's why it did not work.

Comment: @user did you see my answer? I explained also how to enclode the logic in a easy to use method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `else` to print a space when the entry is not a star. Also, I would move the `println()` to the end of the loop (instead of the beginning). Assuming you actually want to fill the `array` too, populate it with a space as well. Like,

```
for (int j = 0; j < _j; j++) {
    if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == _i - 1 || j == _j - 1) {
        array[i][j] = "*";
    } else {
        array[i][j] = " ";
    }
    System.out.print(array[i][j]);
}
System.out.println();
```

Outputs

```
**********
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
**********
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) method, so the code is less verbose, also enclosing the generation in a method you can make it dynamic bu setting two arguments: number of lines and number of columns:

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(createBox(10, 10));
        System.out.println(createBox(10, 5));
    }

    public static String createBox(int qtaRig, int qtaCol)
    {
        String result = "";
        for(int r = 1; r <= qtaRig; r++)
        {
            if(r == 1 || r == qtaRig)
            {
                result += "*".repeat(qtaCol);
            }
            else
            {
                result += "*" + " ".repeat(qtaCol-2) + "*";
            }
            result += "\n";
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
**********
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
**********

*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*   *
*   *
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```